# How can I toggle between the classes of an element inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle between the classes of an element inside a  loop when a button is clicked. Here's a sample of what I thought was going to work.

https://jsfiddle.net/WPederzoli/ts5tm4h6/

```
$(function()    {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $('p.firstClass').toggleClass('secondClass');
    }
  });   
});
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop?

Comment: I wanted it to keep toggling for an x number of times without the need of clicking the button again.

Comment: Are you trying to toggle between both classes?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to toggle between them each time the for loop runs. For example: 1 click = 10 toggles.

Comment: Then you should only have one class, eg. `.classToToggle`, and just use `$('p.elementToToggleClass').toggleClass('classTotoggle');` on an element like `<p class="elementToToggleClass">`

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I'm getting how is that different than the fiddle that I have?

$(function() {
 $('button').on('click', function() {
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     $('p.firstClass').toggleClass('secondClass');
    }
  }); 
});

Comment: Never mind, I just realized that, but why do you need to toggle it 10 times, and do you need a delay between the two

Comment: The code above is just an example of what I would like to accomplish. The thing is I can't figure out how come the toggleClass(); doesn't work inside the for loop.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, the problem is with your css

Answer (score 2):

No need any loop to toggle class.Also you have typo mistake at the class name.class name is `fistClass` not `firstClass`.

```js
$(function() {
 $('button').on('click', function() {

     $('p.fistClass').toggleClass('secondClass');
    
  }); 
});
```

```css
.fistClass {
  color:red;
}
.secondClass {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="fistClass">
Some text!
</p>
<button type="button">
Click Me!
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about the typo, I just did that code to illustrate what I meant. The loop is necessary because in the actual code I'm working on there's a random number assigned to the for loop which makes it run every time the button is clicked. 
Even with the typos corrected, and the jQuery library selected it won't work as I expect.

Comment: No need any loop to handle click event. `toggleClass` automatically works.

Comment: What I meant is that with one click it keeps toggling for an x number of times.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution to your problem. First you need to add in Jquery for Fiddle. (click Javascript) Then change 'fist' to 'first'. And finally remove the loop.

https://jsfiddle.net/Nhawdge/qwo2cvkb/

```
HTML: 
<body>
<p class="firstClass">
Some text!
</p>
<button type="button">
Click Me!
</button>
</body>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function()    {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        $('p.firstClass').toggleClass('secondClass');
  });   
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just did that code to illustrate what I wanted to accomplish in the actual code I'm working on. The loop is there because that block needs to run a random number of times every time the button is clicked. Even without the typo and the jQuery library selected it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because the styles for `.firstClass` are overriding the styles for `.secondClass`, I would do something like

```js
$(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $('p.toggleMe').toggleClass('secondClass');
  });
});
```

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

.secondClass {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="toggleMe">
  Some text!
</p>
<button type="button">
Click Me!
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks again but  if I add the for loop it's still not working. I mean to do something like this:

$(function() {
 $('button').on('click', function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){$('p.firstClass').toggleClass('secondClass')}, 2000);
    }
  }); 
});